# Boot to Btrfs snapshot in Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, filesystem, btrfs, snapshot

OpenSuse recently implemented an GRUB entry that allows you to boot directly into a previous Btrfs snapshot of your root. Is there any way of bringing it to my Ubuntu installation?

Such feature would be really useful, because it makes more straightforward to restore previous system states.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshot in BTRFS is a form of subvolume. By default, your Ubuntu installer on BTRFS created two subvolumes - @ and @home. If you create there a snapshot, say @backup, then you can boot from it by editing grub settings during boot to change the root subvolume name from @ to @backup. You may need to edit @backup/etc/fstab too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you provide instructions on how to do that?

Comment: Well, this is rather adavanced move. Research into BTRFS at BTRFS Wiki and Arch linux wiki, then look for grub configuration there too. This is not a one line solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Git repository that promises to solve that problem:
https://github.com/Antynea/grub-btrfs

It provides a script and configuration to put to /etc/grub.d and /etc/default, respectively.